# Responsive Web Application Template User / Registration Implementation asp.net Web Form

Tags: devexpress

hi am a beginner level developer. I need some information I am using [DevExpress](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/120713/whats-installed/visual-studio-integration/template-gallery/responsive-web-application-template)

I am unable to implement web form security here is my class detail

```
using System.Web;

namespace SECODMS.Model {

public class ApplicationUser {      


    public string UserName { get ; set; }
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }
}

public static class AuthHelper {
    public static bool SignIn(string userName, string password) {         
        HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] = GetLoggedInUserInfo();
        return true;
    }
    public static void SignOut() {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] = null;
    }
    public static bool IsAuthenticated() {
        return GetLoggedInUserInfo() != null;
    }

    public static ApplicationUser GetLoggedInUserInfo()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] as ApplicationUser;
    }
    private static ApplicationUser CreateDefualtUser() {
        return new ApplicationUser {
           
            UserName ="vvnbnbnb",
            FirstName = "Julia",
            LastName = "Bell",
            Email = "julia.bell@example.com",
            AvatarUrl = "~/Content/Photo/Julia_Bell.jpg"
        };
    }
}
}
```

here is my signing Page code

[image: Login Implementation Code]

how to implement user-based web form security?

this is my first post so in case of any mistake sorry in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the code where you setup the session, you are using

`Session["user"] = UserNameTextBox;`

This is wrong, because you have to create an instance of Application user and then set that as the value for the `"user"` key. In the `GetLoggedInUserInfo()`, you are getting the value from session and then casting as `ApplicationUser`. This will always return null as the cast fails.

Fix the session initialization and the login flow will work